# Can I put a variable = another variable in if statements. Or put var = value = another value which it should be equal to?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to work on a problem solving webpage that I need for school but so far I'm stuck with the if statement which it will use to calculate. 
What I have so far.

```
<script>
var randomNumberA = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) +1)
var randomNumberB = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) +1)
document.write('He runs at ' + randomNumberA + 'm/s which took him ' + randomNumberB + 's. How    far did he run?');
var distance = randomNumberA * randomNumberB

function Submit()
{
    var answer = document.getElementById('answer')
    if(distance == true){
    alert("Congrats! You got it right!");
    } else{
    alert("Try again!");
    location.reload();
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<input type='text' id='inputAnswer'/>
<input type='button' onClick='Submit()' value='Submit'/> 
</body>
```

It's not really working and if I put only one "=" then it'll alert as true as long as there's a value in the text box. I plan to make a variable for the textbox value and a variable for the formula and just put If(var1=var2)... so on, but it doesn't work. I'd like to know if it's possible, and if it is how?

If it's not possible can I try to place var1 = formula = textbox id. I'm trying to make it so one variable contains the values that need to be equal so when I declare it in the if statement, I'll just test if it's true or false.

All help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: *"It's not really working"* is considered a very vague error description.

Comment: Could you explain your problem better? I'm really at a lost of what you want to do.

Comment: Cheers, hope you're good now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare the calculated distance to the given answer. Now you compare distance to `true`, which doesn't make sense.

Change it to

```
if(distance == parseFloat(answer.value)){
```

You need `.value`, because `answer` points to the element. You don't want to compare `distance` to the element, but to the numeric representation of the element's value.

Also note that you have the id wrong. In html it is `inputanswer`, while in your script you called it `answer`.

The version with a single `=` works, because you assign a value to distance. An assignment can also be used as an expession, which returns the value that was assigned. So if you write `if (distance = true)`, you assign `true` to the variable `distance`, and also return `true` from the expression, resulting in the code inside the if always being executed.

I've made the necessary fixes in the code below, which you can just run from here. As you can see, you were almost there. I just needed to make those two small fixes. :)

```js
var randomNumberA = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) +1)
var randomNumberB = Math.round((Math.random() * 50) +1)
document.write('He runs at ' + randomNumberA + 'm/s which took him ' + randomNumberB + 's. How    far did he run?');
var distance = randomNumberA * randomNumberB

function Submit()
{
    var answer = document.getElementById('inputAnswer')
    if(distance == parseFloat(answer.value)){
    alert("Congrats! You got it right!");
    } else{
    alert("Try again!");
    location.reload();
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type='text' id='inputAnswer'/>
<input type='button' onClick='Submit()' value='Submit'/> 
</body>
```

Comment: YES!!! THANK YOU!! It works like a charm. 
Oh and the id's were sorta wrong because I was experimenting. Must've copy pasted the wrong version haha.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure that I understand your question. But, here's some info that will hopefully help:

`if(distance == true){`

This will render true if there's a value, unless the value is set to false. It's like saying:

`if (distance)`

If you want to test to see if the value matches the formula, you would just do something like this:

```
function Submit()
{
    var answer = document.getElementById('inputAnswer').value // not 'answer'
    if(distance === answer){
    alert("Congrats! You got it right!");
    } else{
    alert("Try again!");
    location.reload();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps

you could also get the value via JQuery if your'e using that. It would be the following:

```
var answer = $('#inputAnswer').val();
```

Cheers!

Comment: *"It's like saying: `if (distance)`"* No it's not! `if (" " == true)` is `false`, but `if (" ")` is `true`. Type coercion makes this is tricky thing. That said, in this particular case, `distance` is a number and it should be equivalent.

Comment: @FelixKling Actually if it's any number that is not `1` it's false. For example: `if( 15 == true )` is `false`.